# I installed and (tried to) uninstall KDE Plasma, now Unity is messed up

Tags: unity, plasma

I've done

```
unity --reset
```

and

```
reboot
```

and that fixed some problems, but the cursor, desktop icons, and other small things are still affected by installing Plasma. I've done everything I can to remove as much of Plasma as is possible but it still lingers.

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

How do I set Unity to default without messing up where I've placed my launcher icons?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the cursor problem by deleting the breeze cursor theme folders from the /usr/share/icons folder

```
sudo rm -r /usr/share/icons/breeze*
```